# insert in simple linked list doesn't get last line

Tags: linked-list, fgets, singly-linked-list

I am trying to insert into a simply linked list from a file. Do you
 guys have any idea why the function doesn't insert the last line in my
 file?

**This is the file:**

- 10,Ghidul Ciberbobocului,Stan Daria,3,Popescu Matei,Ionescu    Gigel,Ilinca Radu,100.5
- 2,Spring IT,Mirodene Cristina,4,Dumitru    Mihai,Vasiliu    Valentin,Balasa Silvia,Dumitru Ion,400.
- 89,Serile teatrului studentesc,Petre Ion,2,Nicolae Ramona,Stan    Alberto,1000
- 1,Tutoring,Petre Miruna,2,Bode Cristina,Angelescu Paul,500.5
- 11,IT Fest,Ciurea Ion,2,Ionescu Georgiana,Neagu Bianca,100.6

**My code:**

```
struct Proiect {
    int id;
    char* numeProiect;
    char* numeCoordonator;
    unsigned int nrStudenti;
    char**  studenti;
    float costInscriere;
};

struct nodLista {
    Proiect proiect;
    nodLista *next;
};

nodLista* inserareNod(nodLista *first, Proiect p) {
    nodLista* newNode = new nodLista;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->proiect = p;

    if (!first) {
        return newNode;
    }

    nodLista* aux = first;
    while (aux->next) {
        aux = aux->next;
    }

    aux->next = newNode;
    printf("%d\n", aux->proiect.id);
    return first;
}

void main() {
    nodLista* first = NULL;
    Proiect proiect;


    FILE *f = fopen("proiecte2.txt", "r");
    char line[150];
    int nrProiecte = 0;
    if (f) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
            nrProiecte++;
        }
        printf("Nr proiecte: %d",nrProiecte);
        fclose(f);
    }
    else {
        printf("Fisierul nu a fost gasit");
    }

    f = fopen("proiecte2.txt", "r");
    char *token[150], sep_list[] = ",";
    Proiect* listaProiecte;
    listaProiecte = (Proiect*)malloc(nrProiecte * sizeof(Proiect));
    int i = 0;

    if (f) {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
            token[0] = strtok(line, sep_list);
            listaProiecte[i].id = atoi(token[0]);


            first = inserareNod(first, listaProiecte[i]);
            i++;
        }

    }
    else printf("Fisierul nu aputut fi deschis");

}
```

**Output:** It only displays 10 , 2, 89 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make prints inside this function to check if it's doing the while correctly?

```
 while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
            token[0] = strtok(line, sep_list);
            listaProiecte[i].id = atoi(token[0]);


            first = inserareNod(first, listaProiecte[i]);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: I just made prints inside this function and it does read all the lines.

Comment: Ok, I think this is right. I just made this in paper and it works fine except the printf itself. You are printing always the "aux". When you put the last element, you are printing the element behind
`
Example:
inserting: **89**
Current aux after while: **aux = 2**
Element to insert: **aux ->next = 89**
List state: **10 -> 2 -> 89 -> null**
printf(... aux) //**output: 2**
`
So I think you never reach the last element while printing but the elements are being well inserted. Do another function to print